# PHP 2 array loops - mixing up

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a bit of a stange request, so I have 2 arrays

```
$students = array (
array(
"id" => 1,
"name" => "Sarah",
"grade" => "B"
),
array(
"id" => 2,
"name" => "David",
"grade" => "D"
)
);
```

and

```
$lessons = array (
array(
"id" => 1,
"name" => "Maths",
"grade" => "005"
),
array(
"id" => 2,
"name" => "English",
"code" => "003"
),
array(
"id" => 3,
"name" => "Science",
"code" => "007"
),
array(
"id" => 4,
"name" => "Music",
"code" => "001"
)
);
```

Normally, I use something like

```
foreach($students as $student)
{
    echo '<h1>'.$student['name'].' - '.$student['grade'].'</h4>';
}
```

to loop through the arrays, and this is good for certain things.

Please be mindful that sometimes I have only 1 student in the "students" array, sometimes around 30, and sometimes I have 1 lesson in the "lessons" array and sometimes 50.

But in my example, I have just included 2 students and 4 lessons.

So what I would like to do, is combine those 2 arrays and create an output that looks something like

Sarah

Maths

English

David

Science

Music

If I happened to have 5 students and 2 lessons, it would look like

Student

Student

Lesson

Student

Student

Lesson

Student

If I had 2 students and 2 lessons, it would look like

Student

Lesson

Student

Lesson

If I had 3 students and 1 lesson, it would look like

Student

Lesson

Student

Student

and if I just had 2 students and no lessons, it would look like

Student
Student

it's pretty hard for me to explain what this kind of sorting is called

Any help would be amazing, i'm bashing my head trying to work out how to adapt the foreach loop

Comment: So this task is about distributing the two arrays evenly and there are no relationships between the two arrays?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29382138/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/18562683/2943403 ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two parts to this:

1. Determine how many lessons per student, or students per lesson
2. Use that ratio to output an interleaved list

If we use [whole-number division](https://php.net/intdiv) to divide the larger number by the smaller, we get our ratio; we just need to keep track of which around it was:

```php
$numStudents = count($students);
$numLessons = count($lessons);

if ( $numLessons >= $numStudents ) {
    $studentSliceSize = 1;
    $lessonSliceSize = intdiv($numLessons, $numStudents);
}
else {
    $studentSliceSize = intdiv($numStudents, $numLessons);
    $lessonSliceSize = 1;
}
```

Now, we can [take slices](https://www.php.net/array_slice) of each array, ["unpack" them with the `...` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list), and [push them](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) onto the end of a combined list:

```
$combinedArray = [];

$nextStudent = 0;
$nextLesson = 0;

while ( $nextStudent < $numStudents || $nextLesson < $numLessons ) {
    $studentSlice = array_slice($students, $nextStudent, $studentSliceSize);
    array_push($combinedArray, ...$studentSlice);
    $nextStudent += $studentSliceSize;
    
    $lessonSlice = array_slice($lessons, $nextLesson, $lessonSliceSize);
    array_push($combinedArray, ...$lessonSlice);
    $nextLesson += $lessonSliceSize;
}
```

Here is [a live demo](https://3v4l.org/8uEGr) putting that together into a function.

Comment: This is truely amazing, I thank you so much for all your help, and the demo was awesome, thank you